# Can't get members of other domains and PS version

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am learning to create new objects and combine properties from other objects. In this script I want to find out what the PS version is and also add some other properties like OS, IP etc... but I am running into 2 problems. We have 6 domains and I can't seem to iterate over each domain. I tried `(Get-ADForest).Domains` and can see the list of domains. It still only returns objects in the domain my workstation belongs to. The second issue is the `Invoke-Command`. The version always returns 5. I know many of the servers being returned do not have PSVersion 5.

```
function Get-PSVersion {
    (Invoke-Command -Scriptblock {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion}) | Select Major
}

$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and (OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server* *")} -Properties * |
           ForEach-Object {
               $ps = Get-PSVersion
               $server = $_

               New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                   Name      = $server.Name
                   OS        = $server.OperatingSystem
                   IPAddress = $server.IPv4Address
                   Location  = $server.CanonicalName
                   PSVersion = $ps.Major
               }
           }
$servers | Select Name,Location,OS,IPAddress,PSVersion | FT -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so starting with the Invoke-Command, You need to tell that cmdlet which server to target, just calling it as you loop over server names will keep calling it on your local computer, so you'll need to use the -computername parameter, and provide your function an argument to pass to invoke-command.  Which would look something like this:

```
function Get-PSVersion($name) {
    (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name  -Scriptblock {$PSVersionTable.psversion | Select Major})
}
```

You'll notice I also moved your select, this isn't strictly necessary but imo it looks cleaner and means slightly less data gets sent over the network.  note that this will create an object with a single property called Major, if you want just the version number returned as an integer you'd want to do it like this

```
function Get-PSVersion($name) {
    (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name  -Scriptblock {$PSVersionTable.psversion.Major})
}
```

You'll need to add an extra loop into the script if you want to target more than one domain, basically you want an array of the domains you wish to target and then loop over that array calling get-adcomputer for each and specifying the domain name for the -server parameter.  I've put a simplified example below you can incorporate into your own code.

```
$arr = @("test.domain","othertest.domain")

    foreach($domain in $arr){
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Server $domain
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it doesn't work for me. The output is now leaving out the PSversion, Location, OS, and IP. It is returning only the Name of the machine.

Comment: Just ran the function on one of my machines and it returned the version number as expected.  can you post your current code?

Comment: function Get-PSVersion($server) {
    (Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server  -Scriptblock {$PSVersionTable.psversion.Major})
}
$arr = @("myDomain.local","myDomain.local")

    foreach($domain in $arr){
$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and (OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server* *")} -Server $domain  -Properties * |Select -First 5
           ForEach-Object {
               $ps = Get-PSVersion
               $server = $_
Everything below is the same as I originally posted above. thanks again

Comment: If I use this snippet I can return the PSVersion but can't get it to work within my script                                                                                function Get-PSVersion {
    (Invoke-Command  -Computername $server -Scriptblock {$PSVersionTable.psversion})
    }

$servers=Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "DC=,DC=local" -Server ".local" -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and (OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server* *")} -Properties *| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
$sa = foreach($server in $servers)
{
    Get-PSVersion
}

Comment: so immediately I see that a pipe is missing between the select and the foreach-object.  assuming that is a transcription error going from there you need to make sure that when you assign `$ps` you provide the argument, in this case `$_.name`, otherwise powershell doesn't know what computer to target.  finally you added an 's' to your assignment of `$server = $_`, making it `$servers = $_`, which breaks your object assignment, finally you need to drop the `.Major` off of $ps since you are selecting that property in your function.  I think that's everything.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Thanks for the assistance.

```
clear-host
$arr = @("x.local","x.local")

foreach($domain in $arr){
$servers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and (OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server* *")}-Server $domain -Properties *|Select -First 10)
}
$MasterList = @()
foreach ($server in $servers) {
$MyObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Name = $server.Name
Os   = $server.OperatingSystem
Ip   = $server.IPv4Address
PSV  = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server.Name -ScriptBlock {$PSVersionTable.psversion}
}
$MasterList += $MyObj
}
$MasterList|Select Name,PSV,OS,IP
```